# How to create a Pixmap from an OrthographicCamera in LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, camera

I am trying to create a picture based on what one of my `OrthographicCamera` can see. LibGDX has a `ScreenUtils` class that has a `getFrameBufferPixels` method, but it does not what I want as I want to get only what one camera sees, not the whole screen.

Answer (score 3):

You need to render what the camera sees to an FBO and then get the pixmap from the FBO itself.

```
// Construct an FBO and keep a reference to it. Remember to dispose of it.
final FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB565, width, height, false);

//In your render method
//Start rendering to the fbo.
fbo.begin();
//From the camera's perspective.
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
batch.begin();

//Draw whatever you want to draw with the camera.

batch.end();
// Finished drawing, get pixmap.
Pixmap pixmap = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(0, 0, width, height);
//Stop drawing to your fbo.
fbo.end();

//Now you can draw your normal screen as usual.
```

This will draw whatever you draw with your batch to your FBO from your camera's perspective. Remember to reset the projection matrix when you want to render from your main camera.

Comment: What is the utility of `ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(flipY);` if I will get the `Texture` with `fbo.getColorBufferTexture();`

Comment: @CedricMartens Not sure what the exact reason for that is but one reason might be that that method doesn't require you to know about the frame buffer that's currently in use. Hence it can be used for other OpenGL stuff that require you to know of the pixels.

Comment: Yeah and I can't seem to get it into a Pixmap from since it gives me a `GdxRuntimeException` `This TextureData implementation does not return a Pixmap`

and when I try by doing `byte[] bytes = ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixels(false);
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(bytes, 0, bytes.length);` I'll get another `GdxRuntimeException` saying `Couldn't load pixmap from image data`

Comment: @CedricMartens That's because that constructor takes _image data_ not _pixel data_ i.e a png / jpg similar file. You actually have to do some slight hacking to get a pixmap from the pixels. I updated my answer with the solution (bottom of first code block).

Comment: After writing my `Pixmap` to a .png using `PixmapIO.writePNG()`, I keep getting a corrupted .png. I'm wondering a few things. How does the `Pixmap` get the new values? Does `buffer.put()` modify the `Pixmap`? The `FrameBuffer` uses RGB565, but the `Pixmap` RGBA8888, is there a reason behind it?

Comment: @CedricMartens That might be the cause. Try changing the frame buffer to `RGBA8888` instead. Editing the buffer should edit the pixmap since the buffer is the data of the pixmap. `PixmapIO` also uses this buffer to get the pixel data if you look at the source code.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the cause to the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60929/discussion-between-cedric-martens-and-charanor).

Comment: @CedricMartens Hi I've updated my answer with the actual solution. I can't believe I didn't see this before!!

Comment: Are you sure this works 100%? When I use `PixmapIO.writePNG(pixmap)`, I get something that is corrupted. It's quite a hassle to debug as it is a mobile app. If I use Android Studio's debugger I copy the content of `Gdx.files.local("filename").readString()` and put it a new png file `new.png` I get a corrupted file. I also tried sharing the picture with a share intent, but Facebook Messenger, Google drive and Gmail won't send it since it says the file is corrupted.

Comment: @CedricMartens I'm using this right now for my own project and it works fine!